# Reading a dictionary from within a dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a `json` file for tweet data. The data that I want to look at is the text of the tweet.  For some reason, some of the tweets are too long to put into the normal text part of the dictionary.

It seems like there is a dictionary within another dictionary and I can't figure out how to access it very well.

Basically, what I want in the end is one column of a data frame that will have all of the text from each individual tweet.  Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q-ele3faEJkx1e065x1mMw3k9aVC1JGBpCPp5geCmDM/edit?usp=sharing) to a small sample of the data that contains a problem tweet.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
tweets = []
#This writes the json file so that I can work with it.  This part works correctly.
with open("filelocation.txt") as source
    for line in source:
        if line.strip():
            tweets.append(json.loads(line))
print(len(tweets)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tweets)
df.info()
```

When looking at the info you can see that there will be a column called extended_tweet that only encompasses one of the two sample tweets. Within this column, there seems to be another dictionary with one of those keys being full_text.

I want to add another column to the dataframe that just has this information along with the normal text column when the full_text is null.

My first thought was to try and read that specific column of the dataframe as a dictionary again using:

```
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tweets['extended_tweet]['full_text])
```

But this doesn't work.  I don't really understand why that doesn't work as that is how I read the data the first time.

My guess is that I can't look at the specific names because I am going back to the list and it would have to read all or none.  The error it gives me says "KeyError: 'full_text' "

I also tried using the recommendation provided by this [website](https://www.haykranen.nl/2016/02/13/handling-complex-nested-dicts-in-python/).  But this gave me a `None value` no matter what.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to do what @Dan D. suggested, however, this still gave me errors.  But it gave me the idea to try this:
    tweet[0]['extended_tweet']['full_text']
This works and gives me the value that I am looking for.  But I need to run through the whole thing.  So I tried this:
    df['full'] = [tweet[i]['extended_tweet']['full_text'] for i in range(len(tweet))

This gives me "Key Error: 'extended_tweet' "
Does it seem like I am on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the answer suggested earlier works.  I never got that successfully.  But I did figure out something else that works well for me.
What I really needed was a way to display the full text of a tweet.  I first loaded the tweets from the json with what I posted above.  Then I noticed that in the data file, there is something called truncated.  If this value is true, the tweet is cut short and the full tweet is placed within the

```
tweet[i]['extended_tweet]['full_text]
```

In order to access it, I used this:

```
tweet_list = []
for i in range(len(tweets)):
    if tweets[i]['truncated'] == 'True':
        tweet_list.append(tweets[i]['extended_tweet']['full_text']
    else:
        tweet_list.append(tweets[i]['text']
```

Then I can work with the data using the whol text from each tweet.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to flatten out the dictionaries like this:

```
tweet = json.loads(line)
tweet['full_text'] = tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text']
tweets.append(tweet)
```

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail about how I would implement it this way? Sorry, I am a beginner.